# WPF DataGrid Skips Pages When Adding Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that may show many rows worth of data (> 1,000,000), so I am trying to implement a mechanism that will load in data as the user scrolls near the bottom of the current data. I think I've implemented it correctly, but I see a peculiar issue where if I use the scroll wheel on my mouse around the point where it will get the next page of data, the viewport will automatically go to near the bottom of the next page that was just loaded. This does not happen every time, nor does it ever happen when using the keyboard to navigate through the DataGrid.

I've included simplified code below that reproduces my issue. Note that I've used BinderList and DataTable as the ItemsSource, with the same effect. Also, I understand that I don't have any protections here for hitting the end of my data source, nor do I have alot of checks that I need for production code. This is mainly proof of concept code.

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableCollection<int> TableData
    {
        get
        {
            return _myTable;
        }
    }

    ...

    private void DG1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentRow - RowBufferSize < e.Row.GetIndex())
        {
            AddPageToTable();
        }
    }

    private bool AddPageToTable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PageSize; i++)
        {
            _myTable.Add(_newDataEnumerator.Current);
            _newDataEnumerator.MoveNext();
            _currentRow++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" LoadingRow="DG1_LoadingRow">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data"  Binding="{Binding}" Width="400"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing this random skip, or is there any way for me to prevent the viewport from shifting on me?